# Why the function is not working in circular Linked list?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, circular-list

Here is the piece of code in java for inserting node at the end of the circular linked list, but its not working using this function but when I saw in the internet and used that then it worked. Can anyone suggest me that what is wrong with this piece of code?

//PUSH NODE AT END IN CIRCULAR LL

```
public void pushEnd(int new_data){
    Node new_node = new Node(new_data);
    if(head == null){
        head = new_node;
        new_node.next = head;
    }
    else{
        Node temp = head;
        while(temp.next!=null){
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        temp.next = new_node;
        new_node.next = head;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is going wrong?

Comment: `I saw in the internet and used that then it worked`, please give the link where you saw it?

Answer (score 2):

Does any node in a circular linked list have its `next` field as `null` ? If it is, then its not a circular linked list. In your code you are looping until you find a `null` for the `next`. In fact after the first inserted node , for the next insert the loop `while ( temp.next != null )` never ends.

You need to get to the node whose `next` is `head`, that's your last node for the moment. You need to push your new node after that.

So your code should be:

```
public void pushEnd(int new_data){
 Node new_node = new Node(new_data);
   if(head == null){
     head = new_node;
     new_node.next = head;
   }
   else{
     Node temp = head;
     while(temp.next!=head){
       temp = temp.next;
     }
     temp.next = new_node //assign the temp's next to new_node.

     new_node.next = head; //then assign new_node's next to head
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a circular list. `temp.next` will never be null, and so your while loop will never end. You need to change your logic a bit and check when `temp.next == head`.